# How to prove if a relation is transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Like, if $(a,b)$ belongs to $R$ and $(b,c)$ belongs to $R$, then if $(a,c)$ also belongs to $R$, it is a transitive relation.  Can we take $(b,b)$ in place of $(b,c)$ so that it comes out $(a,b)$ belongs to $R$, and $(b,b)$ belongs to $R$, which means $(a,b)$ belongs to $R$ if the relation is transitive.  Is this valid?. Can we take $b=c $ to prove transitivity? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relation $R$ defined in $E$ is transitive $\iff$

$$\forall (a,b,c)\in E^3$$

$a  $ R $  b$ and $b $ R $ c \implies a$  R $ c.$

to prove no transitivity, you need find $(u,v,w)\in E^3\;\;:\;$

$u $ R $v \;, v$  R $w $  but $ u \not $ R  $  w$.